# US Army stations in France during World war 2

Tags: france, world-war-two

My grandpa served in World War 2 as a technical Sergeant for the Signal corps (414 signal company).  He kept a very extensive list of everywhere he traveled and I'm trying to put together a map of all of these places for him.  One place he listed was `Ecramarville` .  I've searched everywhere but cannot find a city with a name like this.

I'm hoping somebody out there knowledgeable in European geography, especially as it relates to World War 2, can help me out.  The previous entry was `boarded boat at Southampton for France.`  This gives me a reason to believe the city is in France.  The entry immediately following this is `Rennes` , which is also in France.

Comment: Welcome to [History.SE]. Perhaps more information would help, such as the unit he was with. If unsuccessful here, you could try [Travel.SE].

Answer (score 4):

Could your place be

Equemauville? Its on the coast, but not near Rennes.
https://www.google.com/maps/place/%C3%89quemauville,+France/@49.403432,0.2092025,13z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x47e032e5d20e4639:0x434c62c2074eeb9

Comment: But it is close to Rouen...

Comment: Équeurdreville This one is on the coast, nearer to Rennes, but doesn't sound as close.

https://www.google.com/maps/place/%C3%89queurdreville-Hainneville,+France/@49.6559158,-1.6569231,13z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x480c9665ccb3b083:0x40c14484fb97bf0

Comment: Équemauville (near Honfleur and Le Havre) would have been in the British/Canadian area of operations in August 1944, while Équeurdreville (near Cherbourg) would have been in the US area. It may also depend on timing

Comment: I think this might be the right place. Plus it lies somewhat between Southampton and Renee, which makes more sense. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In Normandy you'll find Écrammeville, which a young GI who doesn't know French, when reading it from a half destroyed road sign, may well misread as something else.
See https://www.google.nl/maps/place/%C3%89crammeville,+France/@49.5783574,-0.5407385,9z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x480ba721cd54f1fb:0x40c14484fbcf080?hl=en 

From there Rennes may well be a next station.

P.S. Écrammeville is pretty close to Omaha Beach, so may well have been a staging area for units to assemble into marching formation after landing there on the Mulberry harbours.

Comment: That certainly fits the unit. The 414th Signal Company landed at Omaha beach on June 9th, 1944 and was at the time attached to the 70th Fighter Wing of the [404th Air Expeditionary Group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/404th_Air_Expeditionary_Group). The 404th was stationed at [Cricqueville Airfield](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cricqueville_Airfield) until July 10th, which was only about 9km from Écrammeville. They arrived in Rennes on August 8th, 1944. See also [this document](https://www.nsa.gov/about/_files/cryptologic_heritage/publications/wwii/asi_in_northwest_africa.pdf), p. 132-134.

Comment: Écrammeville is less than 2 miles from the Omaha Beach memorial, well behind the end-of-day objectives for June 6; though of course those objectives were not achieved until some days later.